# creating new layers in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx, layer

I want to use layers in my Libgdx application. Could anyone guide me as to how to go about it and to be in the right direction.

I didn't find any layer class to import either.

I need to add layers of text using BitmapFont in my Libgdx app that could be overlapped a little according to the positions tagged by the user. Something similar to how you see tags in Facebook photos.

Comment: I need to add layers of text using BitmapFont in my Libgdx app that could be overlapped a little according to the positions tagged by the user. something like - how you see tags in Facebook photos. Similarly.

Comment: You should write that in your question.

Comment: I tried to add the extra information to the question as you said, but it got rejected apparently. I don understand why though.

Comment: I edited it for you, don't know why you couldn't.

Comment: I did the same copy-paste thing, but it got rejected by 2 reviewers and accepted by 1 reviewer. Wierd.

Comment: I think you have too low rep yet.

Comment: Yup. That must be the reason.